# How to load dynamic two controll for single page?

Tags: angularjs

I want to load two controller on single page. How can i implement?? I am loading controller and view using angularjs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="mainPage>"
    <div data-ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <!-- Stuff related to Ctrl 1 -->
    </div>
    <div data-ng-controller="Ctrl2">
        <!-- Stuff related to Ctrl 2 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever this page is called, both of your controllers will be loaded

Comment: Thanks..But if i am using required js for dynamic loading controller. Then how can i do that??